# How to convert data type from Text to Yes/No inside an append query in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

In MS Access, I'm trying to append data from one table (Table A) into another table (Table B). Table A has a column of type 'Short Text' with a single value 'Even' or empty/null. Table B has an equivalent column of type Yes/No. I've to insert data from Table A to Table B, while doing this conversion - if Table A's column has 'Even' set Table B's value to True, otherwise, set it to False.

I've tried a query like the following but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO TableB( BookName, ChapterName, PageNo, Even)
SELECT name, chapter, page,  IIf(UCase([Even or Odd]) = 'EVEN', True,False)
FROM TableA;
```

The above query gives me following error:

[image: Access Error]

> Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query.
>   Microsoft Access set 0 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure, and it didn't add 117 record(s) to the table due to key violations....

How can I make access change the value while appending the data?

Comment: Your question is clear and OK, but please post the error message and not a link to an image of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error screen says, the problem is not in converting data types, the error is due to key violation. 
Try inserting without this yes/no field, and you'll ensure in this.
You may have relationships between tables so that it doesn't allow to insert certainn values.

Comment: Yep. It was a stupid Number Vs. Autonumber mismatch for the primary key. Turns out the query did work with IIF() for the conversion part.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of any future searches, Here is my final query which did work:

```
INSERT INTO TableB( BookName, ChapterName, PageNo, Even)
SELECT name, chapter, page,  IIf(UCase([Even or Odd])="EVEN",-1,0) AS EvenOdd FROM TableA;
```

Things to check, if there are data type differences between source and destination tables. In my case, the page column in source table was `number` and in destination was `Short Text`.

Also, the Primary key, which isn't part of the query, was `Number` instead of `AutoNumber`, that was failing, and hence I was getting the error.